# Looping over query result versus looping over explicitly declared cursor in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, cursor, database-performance

What is the difference in looping over query result vs looping over explicitly declared cursor in Postgres? Is looping over query result implicitly creating a cursor?

Looping over query result:

```
FOR v_employee IN
    SELECT *
    FROM employee
    WHERE ...
LOOP
    -- Do something with v_employee
END LOOP;
```

Looping over explicitly declared cursor:

```
FOR v_employee IN my_cursor
LOOP
    -- Do something with v_employee
END LOOP;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, looping through a query result will use a cursor implicitly.

The performance should be the same, but the first syntax is often clearer.